# check if field has new value in buddypress xprofile

Tags: wordpress, field, buddypress

When a user updates their profile field "Country" or "City" with a new value, I want to be notified with only the field that has new value. Curently I'm using this but doesn't tell which fiels have been modified:

```
add_action ('xprofile_updated_profile', 'profile_change_notify');
function profile_change_notify ($vars = array ())
{
    $user = new WP_User ($vars['user_id']);
    wp_mail ('myname@mydomain.com', 'Subject ( ' . $user->user_login . ' just updated the Profile )', 'Message Body goes here.');
}
```

I appreciate any help..

Answer (score 0):

Please use  below code:

```
function update_xprofile_country_state($user_id) {
    if (!empty($user_id)) {
            $user = new WP_User ($user_id);
        if (!empty($_POST['country'])) {
                 wp_mail ('myname@mydomain.com', 'Subject ( ' . $user->user_login . ' just updated the Profile )', 'Message Body goes here.');
        }
    }
}
add_action('xprofile_updated_profile', 'update_xprofile_country_state', 0, 1);
```

Here you have got the value from $_POST variable.
If contry value is updated from user profile then send a mail.